# How do I return an error from a Meteor.call method inside another Meteor.call

Tags: meteor

My meteor code goes a couple Meteor.call methods deep at some points. If I have an error in the 2nd layer and I want to throw that meteor error back to the client side how can I do that?

Currently I have something like this, but I'm getting very confusing outputs and I don't think I fully understand what is happening when I'm calling `throw new Meteor.Error(500, e.category_code, e.description);`

In client.js

```
Meteor.call('firstCall', data, function (error, result) {
  if(result) {
    doSomething();
  }
  else{
    console.log(error);//just shows 500
  }
});
```

In server.js

```
var Future = Meteor.npmRequire("fibers/future");

function extractFromPromise(promise) {
    var fut = new Future();
    promise.then(function (result) {
        fut.return(result);
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        fut.throw(error);
    });
    return fut.wait();
}

firstCall: function (data){
  try{
    Meteor.call('secondCall', data, 'http://testhref.com/test', 'http://testhref2.com/test' function (error, result) {
      return result;
    });
  }
  catch(e){
    throw new Meteor.Error(500, e.category_code, e.description);
  }
}

secondCall: function (data, paymentHref, otherHref){
  try{
    var associate = extractFromPromise(balanced.get(paymentHref).associate_to_customer(otherHref).debit({
                "amount": data.paymentInformation[0].total_amount * 100,
                "appears_on_statement_as": "Trash Mountain"}));
  }
  catch(e){
    Collection.update(data.id, {
        $set: {
            'failed.category_code': e.category_code,
            'failed.description': e.description
        }
    });
    throw new Meteor.Error(500, e.category_code, e.description);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the catch in `firstCall` is not going to have anything defined for `e.category_code` and `e.description` when `secondCall` throws. This is because in `secondCall` you are passing these two as arguments to `Meteor.Error`, which takes as its arguments `error`, `reason`, and `details`:

> https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/meteor/errors.js

In order to pass these through, you will need to amend `firstCall` to use these properties:

```
firstCall: function (data){
  try{
    Meteor.call('secondCall', data, 'http://testhref.com/test', 'http://testhref2.com/test');
  }
  catch(e){
    throw new Meteor.Error(500, e.reason, e.details);
  }
}
```

I'm not even sure you need to split it up into two calls for modularity, as you can just use normal Javascript functions. But we can discuss that elsewhere.

Comment: Even this doesn't seem to return the correct information from the error. My example above isn't sufficient to explain the problem. I have my whole firstCall wrapped in a try catch, but when the error is thrown the code seems to continue to execute, which causes another error and that is what is being returned from firstCall to the client.

Comment: Are you calling `secondCall` synchronously? See my revision.

Comment: I wasn't calling it synchronously. That fixed it, but I think there has certainly got to be a better way to get the error down to the client. I'm sure I'm not doing this the best way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I few things to mention here:

0. Async function don't throw exceptions (except you make them kind of sync using `Meteor._wrapAsync` as I will explain later), they return the error on another way (as the first argument in NodeJS callback-style). This applies both for `Meteor.call` and to your `doSomeAsyncThing`.
1. I can't see the benefit of using `Meteor.call` on the server. `Meteor.call` is meant to call server methods from the client. In this case you could just call `YourObj.secondCall` from inside of `firstCall`.
2. Returning something from inside of a callback (as you are doing inside `firstCall`) doesn't have any effect. You want your async code to work as sync code, so I suggest using `Meteor._wrapAsync` which is very well explained [here](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-meteor-wrapasync).
   So, I would implement server side a bit different:

```js
firstCall: function (data){
  try{
    return this.secondCall(data);
  }
  catch(e){
    throw new Meteor.Error(500, e.category_code, e.description);
  }

secondCall: function (data){
  try{
    return Meteor._wrapAsync(doSomeAsyncThing)(data);
  }
  catch(e){
    Collection.update(data.id, {
        $set: {
            'failed.category_code': e.category_code,
            'failed.description': e.description
        }
    });
    throw new Meteor.Error(500, e.category_code, e.description);
  }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok, I updated the question to show the promise async function that I use. I can't use _wrapAsync because it doesn't work with promises. Also, I noticed I missed a couple of } so I put those where they belong. I have my method calls in another file and that is why I was doing another Meteor.call. I suppose I could use a function instead, but I'm trying to make my methods multi-use and I'd like to be able to call them from many different files.